# How should we split a string in perl and store it in two variables

Tags: perl

how can we split the following string in perl:

Input:

```
$string='/path/to/the/file/on/server/date_in_yyyymmdd/filename-yyyymmdd.tar.gz'
```

Output:

```
$string1=/path/to/the/file/on/server/date_in_yyyymmdd
$string2=filename-yyyymmdd.tar.gz
```

Comment: Maybe using [fileparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html#fileparse) from `File::Basename` would be more appropriate that a manual splitting in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Dada, it will try it. For now the solution provided by Srihari has worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expression:

The first `(.*)` is a greedy match and the second `(.*?)` is a non-greedy match so should have only the last part of `/`

```
if($string =~ m/^(.*)\/(.*?)$/)
{
   $string1 = $1;
   $string2 = $2;
}
```

Comment: A greedy quantifier instead of the non-greedy would produce the same result though.

Comment: Would recommend not using `/` as your pattern delimiter, if you're using it in the pattern.  `m,^(.*)/(.*)$,` will work,and you don't need to escape the slash.